# What do the Glyphs from the Tale of Genji represent?

Tags: pattern

The Tale of Genji is a classic japanese novel, probably written more than a thousand years ago. The 19th century artist Toyohara Kunichika painted a picture for every of the [54 chapters](http://www.man-pai.com/Genji/genji.htm).

Every [picture](http://www.man-pai.com/Grandes_series/Kunichika_54sentimentos/kunichika_54sentimentos_52_e.htm) is showing an open book, on the pages of which a glyph is repeated. For each chapter, a different glyph is used (also referred to as *crest* or *Genjimon*). There is a system to their creation.

Examples from two different chapters:

[image: picture example]
[image: glyph example]

Here you can [browse](http://www.man-pai.com/Grandes_series/Kunichika_54sentimentos/kunichika_54sentimentos_modernos1_e.htm) through Kunichika's paintings (there's a previous/next navigation). Unfortunately the [details](http://www.man-pai.com/Grandes_series/Kunichika_54sentimentos/kunichika_54sentimentos_18_e.htm) under chapter 18 are messed up, but one can recognize the pattern anyhow.

**Can you make out the system and the 'mistakes'?**

Edit: It is not necessary to know Japanese. Do not base your deductions on the summary linked to below, the representation of the brushstrokes is deceiving. Use it only to identify the indistinctly painted glyphs. The order of the glyphs is of no importance.

If you find it too hard making them out, view this [glyph summary](http://www.man-pai.com/Artigos/genjimon_e.htm).

<sub>Hint one:</sub>

> <sup>Intersections should be interpreted like this:</sup> [image: interhint]

<sub>Hint two:</sub>

> <sup>Certain glyphs are duplicates in terms of the system.</sup>

<sub>Hint three:</sub>

> <sup>My lucky number can be found [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1955/epimenides-paradox).</sup>

Comment: Do you need to know Japanese?

Comment: Is that glyph summary really accurate? There seem to be some discrepancies with the browsable paintings. For instance, in the [painting for #17](http://www.man-pai.com/Grandes_series/Kunichika_54sentimentos/kunichika_54sentimentos_17_e.htm), the glyph is five vertical lines, all of them joined together except the fourth one, which stands alone. But the summary shows six vertical lines, the second and third standing alone.

Comment: Yes, that's the summary I was comparing the painting to.

Comment: Oh, so the black lines in the summary represent the gap between stripes, not the stripes themselves... Got it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like these represent partitions of a set of 5 items.

But there should be 52 only according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set.

It looks like #35 and #42 in the glyph summary are equivalent.  And #54 doesn't fit with the pattern.  Or it is a funny variation of #53.